# Give a wget downloaded file executable rights without chmod?

Tags: bash, dockerfile, wget

I'm trying to download a binary from nexus from a script/dockerfile
here is my command:

```
wget --user=${NEXUS_USERNAME} --password=${NEXUS_PASSWORD} ${NEXUS_URL}/${ASM_NEXUS_REPO}/${ASM_VERSION} -O ${ASM_DESTINATION_PATH}
```

I wanted to know if wget (or any other linux built-in command that can do the same thing) had a parameter like "-x" to give to a downloaded file the executable rights (instead of running `chmod +x ${ASM_DESTINATION_PATH}` or umask command - only in one unique command -)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Changing the `umask` is a thing, but it'll be ANDed with the inverse of another mask built into the wget source code and passed as an argument to the `open()` syscall, so it's probably not a very effective thing here.

Comment: BTW, as an aside, all-caps variable names are defined by the POSIX standard for shell and system use, whereas names with at least one lowercase letter are reserved for applications (such as your scripts) -- see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that setting a regular shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable, making them effectively share a namespace.

Comment: BTW, what do you mean "linux built-in command"? wget isn't built in any more than anything else is (and some forward-thinking distros have switched to `curl` for their internal use, so wget is less likely to be installed by default than it used to be).

Comment: umask won't gan execution permission to new files. Instead try the wget --preserve-permissions switch... if the file has the exec permissions in remote host it may work.

Comment: @AlfredoCamposEnríquez, umask _can_ give execute permission to new files if the mask passed to `open()` includes +x. It's unlikely that it does, but I'd need to read the wget source (or strace its operation) to know for sure. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your very instructive answers hahaha ! 
AlfredoCamposEnríquez Thanks for your answer, "--preserve-permissions" doesnt work since the file i try to get comes from nexus repo (or maybe it doesnt have the x permission on the server, anyway) 
However, still looking for something that can do the job :p

Comment: `wget [...] && chmod +x ...`.  Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Then why reinvent the wheel with -O just use wget [...] && mv [...] ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. It's as simple as that. Unix permissions are not transferred by HTTP. To do this, you would need to use other tools, e.g. rsync or scp.